# Iterate files by extension and substring search

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have this code

```
for /R "C:\myfiles" %%i in (*super*.ts) do (
echo %%i
)
```

so I want to iterate over all files in the folder `C:\myfiles` which have in the path `super` and end with `.ts`. e.g.

```
"c:\myfiles\foo\bar\super\123.ts"
```

but that substring search doesn't work.

Comment: Your `for /R` loop searches for files whose names contain `super`, but that is not what you actually want, right? But what is it? Do you want only files in a directory named `super` (like `D:\foo\bar\super\item.ts`), or may `super` occur anywhere in the path (like `D:\foo\super\bar\item.ts`), even as partial directory names (like `D:\foo\whatasuperdirectory\bar\item.ts`)?

Comment: @aschipfl that both fits my needs, whichever is easier to apply. I can choose such a directoryname, which will never appear in any of my files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this:

```
dir /S /B C:\myfiles\*.ts | findstr /I "Super"
```

Explanation:

```
dir /S : search in subdirectories
dir /B : show bare format, like C:\myfile\subdir\filename.ts
...
findstr /I : filter is case insensitive
```

result:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /S /B C:\myfiles\*.ts ^| findstr /I "Super"') do echo %%a
```

Comment: and how to loop over the result?

Comment: `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /S /B C:\myfiles\*.ts ^| findstr /I "Super"') do echo %%a`

Answer (score 2):

Your [`for /R`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) loop searches for files whose names contain `super`, but that is not what you want.

If one of the following situations apply, you could use below code snippets:

1. If the word `super` may occur anywhere in the path, even in the file name:

   ```cmd
    for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
        dir /S /B /A:-D-H-S "C:\myfiles\*.ts" ^| findstr /I /C:"super"
    ') do (
        echo(%%F
    )
   ```

   The `/A:-D-H-S` option of [`dir`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) excludes directories as well as hidden and system files.
2. If the word `super` is the name of any directory in the hierarchy:

   ```cmd
    for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
        dir /S /B /A:-D-H-S "C:\myfiles\*.ts" ^| findstr /I /C:"\\super\\"
    ') do (
        echo(%%F
    )
   ```

   The `\\` in the [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) search expression constitutes an escaped `\`.
3. If the word `super` is the name of the immediate parent directory:

   ```cmd
    for /F "delims=" %%F in ('
        dir /S /B /A:-D-H-S "C:\myfiles\*.ts" ^| findstr /I /R /C:"\\super\\[^\\][^\\]*\.ts$"
    ') do (
        echo(%%F
    )
   ```

   The string `\\super\\[^\\][^\\]*\.ts$` is a [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) regular expression, that anchors to the right (`$`) a string that consists of the literal string `\super\` plus a string of at least a character other than `\` and the literal string `.ts`.

   And here is an alternative approach without `findstr` but an [`if` statement](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) instead, together with a standard [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) to resolve the name of the parent directory:

   ```cmd
    for /R "C:\myfiles" %%F in (*.ts) do (
        for %%E in ("%%~F\..") do (
            if /I "%%~nxE"=="super" echo(%%~F
        )
    )
   ```

   This may be faster, because there is no [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) and no [pipe (`|`)](https://ss64.com/nt/redirection.html) involved, both of which instantiate new [`cmd.exe`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) instances.